# loop with rsource inside not working

Tags: r, loops, stata

I am using rsource in order to produce certain variables in this way:

```
set more off
local n 4
local i 100

rsource, terminator(END_OF_R)  rpath(C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.5\bin\R.exe) roptions(`" --vanilla --args "`i'" "`n'" "')



library(foreign)

trailargs <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE);
trailargs;



i<- as.numeric(trailargs[1])
n<- as.numeric(trailargs[2])
y =  n-i
sample = data.frame(y)
path = paste("C:/Users/.../Desktop/sample","_",n,"_test.dta",sep="")
write.dta(sample, path)
END_OF_R
```

This is working, and i do get my sample_100_test.dta
However, i would like to produce a series of these datasets, in this way

```
set more off
local n 4

forvalues i = 1/10 {

rsource, terminator(END_OF_R)  rpath(C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.5\bin\R.exe) roptions(`" --vanilla --args "`i'" "`n'" "')
library(foreign)
trailargs <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE);
trailargs;
i<- as.numeric(trailargs[1])
n<- as.numeric(trailargs[2])

y =  n-i
sample = data.frame(y)
path = paste("C:/Users/.../Desktop/sample","_",n,"_test.dta",sep="")
write.dta(sample, path)
END_OF_R

   ..... within loop
      use  sample","_",n,"_test.dta, clear
   ...estimation
      erase sample","_",n,"_test.dta
  }
```

And this is not working. What is the problem with this loop, why do i get error
"End of R output: command library is unrecognized"

Thanks for suggestions

Comment: I am unfamiliar with this package, but you would probably be more successful writing the loop in R instead of stata. In your loop, you load R 10 times, and then close it. It would be more efficient to load R once, produce all the datasets you want, and then close it.

Comment: In addition, you define "i" three different times in your second script, you should probably use different index variable names (j?) to avoid confusion/interference.

Comment: yes, i corrected that, point is that I need i to change in every loop..

Comment: with R i create dataset, and in fact loop is bigger than 10, more like 500... so in this way i create and replace datasets, otherwise i would need to store that much data... or to think of some third solution

Comment: Personally, I just rely on base functionality in Stata and R: Stata can post command line calls and R can be called from the command line, so `shell "$r_dir\rscript.exe" --default-packages=methods,utils "$myscriptdir\do_stuff.r" 1> "$mylogdir/rlog_do_stuff.log" 2>&1`. Anyway, if you're bootstrapping, I think this is quite inefficient.

Comment: As far as I can tell from your example, you are writing out 10 separate dta files. If you are doing something else in your Stata `forvalues` loop, then you should include something similar in your question.

Comment: thats true, it is bad example, idea is to pass "i" and some other vars as arguments to r, where "i" is used to set seed, and actually "i" is not in the name of the dataset, it is for example n... my simple example is maybe confusing... so i recreate many datasets and do estimations, but with different seeds for simulation purposes

Comment: Thanks Frank, since i need to pass arguments to R in every loop my only solution at the moment is to use argument options in rsource...

Comment: Hm, I've never used it, but the help page (type `?Rscript` in R) suggests that it also supports arguments, and you can see in my example that I'm passing options (`--default-packages=`).

Comment: I just added a seeds `local` that is a Stata macro list that I then use Rs `strsplit` function and `unlist` to make it a numerical vector. Perhaps this will work for a number of these situations.

Comment: Imo i modified my example, and i think now is clear what is the problem with that approach. Lets say i use for seeds sequential numbers as i++ i just pass first one to R. My question is really about making rsource working in loop, for this purpose but for curiosity as well.. In this case problem with your answer is still that i store too many simulated data, and i really dont see it as a solution, even the other is to invoke R in each loop.

Answer (score 2):

This is the approach I would use, which is to increment i within R:

```
set more off
local n 100
local maxi 4
local seeds "1234 12345 123467"

rsource, terminator(END_OF_R)  rpath(C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.5\bin\R.exe) roptions(`" --vanilla --args "`n'" "`maxi'" "`seeds'" "')

library(foreign)
trailargs <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE);
trailargs;

n <- as.numeric(trailargs[1])
maxi <- as.numeric(trailargs[2])
seeds <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(trailargs[3], split=" ")))
print(seeds)    

for(seed in seeds) {
  set.seed(seed)
  for(i in 1:maxi) {
    y =  n-i
    sample = data.frame(y)
    path = paste("C:/Users/.../Desktop/sample","_",i,"_test.dta",sep="")
    write.dta(sample, path)
  }
}
END_OF_R
```

As I said in my comments, this should be a lot more efficient than opening and closing R 10 times.